# Axios - cross domain cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios

I have two applications (backend and frontend) running on local computer (frontend - Vue app on port 8080, backend - Scala app on port 9000)

I'm trying to send request to backend using Axios with cookie, but it works only, if both are running on the same domain:

**It's working (cookie is present in API request):**

*backend address:* http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/systems

*frontend (in browser):* http://127.0.0.1:8080

**It doesn't work (request doesn't contain cookie):**

*backend address:* http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/systems

*frontend (in browser):* http://localhost:8080

My frontend snippet with request:

```
const BASE_URL = appConfig.API_URL + '/api';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.get(BASE_URL + '/systems');
```

I think CORS are configured correctly:

```
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:8080"]
  supportsCredentials = true
  allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
}
```

Comment: Your _CORS_ should likely be `"http://127.0.0.1:9000"`, port `9000`, not `8080`

Comment: Why? Client sends `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in Origin header

Comment: Yes, but in your `allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:8080"]` you didn't used port `9000` for the address `"http://127.0.0.1:8080"` ... makes sense?

Comment: As I know, in `access-control-allow-origin` we should put clients (not server) domains and port 9000 is server port. By the way, I've checked it when I configured cors like: `allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:9000", "http://localhost:9000"]` I'm still unable to put cookies in cross domain requests. And when I changed it to `allowedOrigins = ["http://127.0.0.1:9000", "http://localhost:9000"]`, my browser blocks requests, so it looks, that CORS should be configured with client Origin

Comment: I noticed, that CORS checking is disabled in Chrome (--disable-web-security flag), it's working, so probably something is wrong with my CORS settings, but I've no idea what.

Comment: Now I'm sure, that it isn't related to beckend CORS settings. I've stopped backend service and repeted tests. I've observed, that cookies are sent only, if backend is in the same domain, that frontend (with different port), even if backend is stopped, so dosn't response with any CORE related headers

Comment: I had the same issue, I solved by reverse proxying my backend with nginx, if you control both frontend and backend on the same machine it is a neat solution

Comment: Could You provide proxy settings? I'm affraid, that won't help, because I've the same problem even when backend is down (so fronend is able to set cookie only, when backend is in the same domain. Because it's GET request with standard headers, there is no preflight request)

Comment: Hi, now I'm facing same problem with you. I have react app on port 5000 and api koa server on 5001, no cookie has been included from client request. How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this on the backend:

```
const allowedOrigins = ['localhost',"http://localhost:8080", "http://127.0.0.1:8080","http://localhost:8080/"];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
      console.log("------")
      console.log("origin",origin)
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
}
```

Comment: please add further information

Comment: @thelearner in this im adding multiple domain lists that can be allowed to make requests.

Answer (score -1):

Different ports are considered cross-domain so it's likely not an issue with your CORS setting since in your first example the cross-domain request works. My guess is it's likely something to do with how your front-end treats `localhost`

Answer (score -2):

You need to set header in the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Set-Cookie
```

In express on node.js it's go like this:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Set-Cookie')
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` tells the requester what headers they can use. `Set-Cookie` is a header returned in the response, not the request. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers